# How to check the camera is auto focused in flutter?

Tags: flutter, camera, autofocus

I am using Camera plugin for my flutter app, how can I check the camera preview is focused or not?

Answer (score 1):

Auto Focus will be provided in this milestone, 
based on Future of the Camera Plugin (Refactor/Rework) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31225

IOS part has pull request, please reference [camera] Expose auto exposure and auto focus point of interest functionality (iOS only) https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/709

Comment: So, no work around right now? Anyway , can I access the device camera features to check whether it is focused or not? What I actually need is , I have to capture once the camera is focused..Any solution?

Comment: If you use IOS, you can fork camera plugin and merge pull request of https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/709

Comment: i am using android, then?

Comment: You can ask lsmith130 about his plan and schedule in here https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/709

Comment: Okay, Thank You!